# Trouble while settings drawable images in Arraylist in android

Tags: android, arraylist, imageview, drawable, android-drawable

I want to set images in Array list from drawable here is my code

```
 private ArrayList<Integer>  timeNames = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 timeNames.add(R.drawable.azaan_fajar_eng);
 timeNames.add(R.drawable.azaan_fajar_eng1);
 timeNames.add(R.drawable.azaan_fajar_eng2);
 timeNames.add(R.drawable.azaan_fajar_eng3);
 timeNames.add(R.drawable.azaan_fajar_eng4);
 timeNames.add(R.drawable.azaan_fajar_eng5);
 timeNames.add(R.drawable.azaan_fajar_eng6);
```

this code do not show any error but display integer value instead of image please help me how to resolve it?

Comment: timeNames store images Id and you can fetch images from Drawable as per their Id

Answer (score 2):

You can load images from `Drawable` using `timeNames` like:

```
private ArrayList<Integer> timeNames = new ArrayList<Integer>();
timeNames.add(R.drawable.azaan_fajar_eng);
timeNames.add(R.drawable.azaan_fajar_eng1);
timeNames.add(R.drawable.azaan_fajar_eng2);
timeNames.add(R.drawable.azaan_fajar_eng3);
timeNames.add(R.drawable.azaan_fajar_eng4);
timeNames.add(R.drawable.azaan_fajar_eng5);
timeNames.add(R.drawable.azaan_fajar_eng6);

int[] type_img=new int[]{R.id.img1,R.id.img2,R.id.img3,R.id.img4,R.id.img5,R.id.img6,R.id.img7};

for(int i=0;i<timeNames.size();i++){

((ImageView)findViewById(type_img[i])).setImageResource(timeNames.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following method.

```
List<Integer> mImagesIds= Arrays.asList(R.drawable.image1,R.drawable.image2);
```

Add your drawables to list and use where you need later.

Answer (score 1):

You must remember that your arraylist containt resource ID-s not images. You can retrieve image to ImageView like this:

```
private ArrayList<Integer> timeNames = new ArrayList<Integer>();

timeNames.add(R.drawable.azaan_fajar_eng);
timeNames.add(R.drawable.azaan_fajar_eng1);

// set image for ImageView
imageView.setImageResouce(timeNames.get(i));
```